# Building a complex SwiftUI view made up of structs conforming to Views

Tags: swiftui

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65536210/complex-swiftui-view-performance) I got good advice to use `Equitable` for subviews for performance but I am struggling to implement that.

I have a complex view made up of diverse subviews. The subviews look like this.

```
struct Sub1View < Content : View > : View, Equatable
{
    let x       : Int             // Here x represents some local state
    let content : Content
    var body    : some View
    {
        content
    }

    init ( x : Int, @ViewBuilder content : () -> Content )
    {
        self.x       = x
        self.content = content()
    }

    static func == ( lhs : Sub1View < Content >, rhs : Sub1View < Content > ) -> Bool
    {
        return lhs.x == rhs.x
    }
}

struct Sub2View < Content : View > : View, Equatable
{
    // Similar to above
}
```

I want to use these inside the main view, which looks something like this

```
struct MainView : View
{
    var body : some View
    {
        fn ( x : 1 )
        fn ( x : 2 )
        fn ( x : 3 )
        fn ( x : 4 )
        // more of the same
    }
}
```

That function `fn` can return any one of the subviews and that is where I am stuck. FWIW in reality there are multiple functions, this is a simplified version of the actual code.

I tried implementing the function as follows

```
    func fn ( x : Int ) -> some View
    {
        if x > 5
        {
            return Sub1View ( x : x )
            {
                Button ...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return Sub2View ( x : x )
            {
                Label ...
            }
        }
    }
```

but then I run into `Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types`. I was hoping that `View` would be the common denominator here.

Then I tried

```
    @ViewBuilder
    func fn ( x : Int ) -> some View
    {
        if x > 5
        {
            // No return
            Sub1View ( x : x )
            {
                Button ...
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // No return
            Sub2View ( x : x )
            {
                Label ...
            }
        }
    }
```

and, already frustrated, I got the really meaningful `The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time...`.

It seems I have to add some common protocol to all of them `Sub1View` and `Sub2View` and so on, further layering an already complex thing. Also, each time I add one more such layer the compile time goes up exponentially.

Anyhow, I tried that using a protocol like this

```
protocol SomeSubView
{
    associatedtype ContentType
}
```

but still run into trouble. I am hoping somebody can help me with this please? I would really like to get away without having to add that protocol.

Earlier, before I added the `Equitable`, the function was simply

```
    func fn ( x : Int ) -> some View
    {
        if x > 5
        {
            return Button ...
        }
        else
        {
            return Label ...
        }
    }
```

but now that I want to return `struct`s, that conform to `View`, I am struggling, and I also wonder why I can't simply replace those `Button` and `Label`s with my own `struct`s?

Comment: SwiftUI does not optimise function call (like `fn ( x : 1 )`) and they will be called (with all internals redraw) on every time host `body` called. `Equatable` works when you use View inside `body`, so view is created compared to previous one, but does not re-render if equal - that is rendering optimisation point.

Comment: @Asperi thanks for your help, now and earlier. I was hoping after body was called, somewhere internally there are a bunch of nodes that gets compared and then Equitable makes a difference there. Those views are similar but with small differences, so to make it parameter driven makes sense. I implemented that using functions with parameters, but if it does not help SwiftUI maybe the way to parameterise it then is to use local variables. While it is possible the code will be considerably more bulky and more difficult to maintain then.